# Failed to bind properties under 'azure.servicebus.subscription-receive-mode' to com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.ReceiveMode:

Tags: java, spring, azure

I've been tasked to update a spring boot app that makes use of Microsoft Azure servicebus. 
However, the client claims it runs fine on Azure - but I can't get it to start:

Relevant config:

```
azure:
  notificationConnectionString: Endpoint=sb://voobv.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=xxxx/0XJib3iJA45p1D6Wc=
  notificationHubName: voob
  servicebus:
    connection-string: Endpoint=sb://xxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxxx=
    topic-name: applicationbuildevents
    subscription-name: apiserver_applicationbuildevents
    subscription-receive-mode: PEEKLOCK
```

Error message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'azure.servicebus.subscription-receive-mode' to com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.ReceiveMode:

    Property: azure.servicebus.subscription-receive-mode
    Value: PEEKLOCK
    Origin: class path resource [application.yml]:75:32
    Reason: 0

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

I've googled alot around this but seem to have my hand on an unique problem (and a extremly bad error message from spring/microsoft)

Anyone that have seen similar issues? I'm leaning strongly to remove all servicebus code for now, but would rather keep the code intact...

Comment: You could post you main code, we will test for you.

Comment: There is no code that causes this error. It comes when adding the dependency.